# PhpStorm "right margin" on Mac

Tags: phpstorm

I want to remove the gray vertical line supposedly called "right margin" in PhpStorm on a Mac.

This vertical line needs to have a value so zero cannot be set, reason that I need this is because when I press <kbd>Cmd + Alt + L</kbd> to reformat my code, it breaks the code from that line.

Comment: so .. just set it to some very big value (e.g. 1000 or higher if possible) -- it will be in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`

Comment: yes I tried that, but unfortunately no luck

Comment: And "no luck" means what exactly? Is it still breaks at the same place .. or you cannot set the big enough margin (e.g. you prefer to write over 1000-characters long lines (because 1000 seems to be accepted just fine)). Few notes: 1) this margin can also be set at per language level 2) if you have `.editorconfig` files support then settings from there will overwrite your IDE settings 3) You can configure your formatter to not to wrap when reaching right margin (just choose other option)

Comment: thanks for your comment, but with no luck I mean that it cannot be set to a higher value, it won't apply. Acceptable range is 80, 120, 180 which in my case is useless because of mine wide screen monitor, other options like 0 or 1000 won't apply I also tried to set to 200 but that also won't apply.

Comment: I just put like 1000 and it accepted it (PhpStorm v10.0.3 -- latest stable)...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to disable this right margin line.

In PhpStorm(on a Mac):

`File -> Default Settings -> Editor > General > Appearance`

uncheck the: [image]

`Show right margin(configured in Code Style options)`

That worked perfect for me.